# Automatically update id variable in two controllers using $broadcast in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, broadcast

```
$ctrl.clicker = function(id)
{
   $rootScope.$broadcast('idBull', id);
}
```

When I mouseenter an image the above function gets called. I want to share the id in another controller and broadcast whatever changes where made to this id.

```
$scope.$on('idBull', function (event, data) {
  console.log(data); // 'Data to send'
});
```

In the other controller I used the code to do a console loge of my id but got no results.

Comment: Rather than do this it seems like you should be using a service

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/87rLob9x/
Check this fiddle hope it helps
html

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller='ControllerA'>

    <button ng-click='add()'>Add</button
</div>
<div ng-controller='ControllerB'>
    {{ increment }}

</div>

</html>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('ControllerA', function($scope) {
    $scope.increment = 0;
    $scope.add = function() {
        $scope.$broadcast('hasIncremented');
    }

}).
controller('ControllerB', function($scope) {
    $scope.$on('hasIncremented', function(event) {
        $scope.increment++; 
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are not getting your code to work, maybe the controller with `$scope.$on` is not created/loaded when the `$rootScope.$broadcast` is executed?

Another solution is to use a service that you inject into both controllers and use that for communication instead. Example of broadcast solution:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])
.controller("ControllerA", function($scope, $rootScope)
{
    $scope.clicker = function(id)
    {
        $rootScope.$broadcast("id changed", id);
    }
})
.controller("ControllerB", function($scope)
{
    $scope.$on("id changed", function(event, id)
    {
        // Do whatever you need to do with id
    });
});
```

Example of solution with custom service:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [])
.factory("customService", function()
{
    var callbacks = [];

    return {
        onIdChange: function(callback)
        {
            callbacks.push(callback);
        },
        idChanged: function(id)
        {
            callbacks.forEach(function(callback)
            {
                callback(id);
            });
        }
    };
})
.controller("ControllerA", function($scope, customService)
{
    $scope.clicker = function(id)
    {
        customService.idChanged(id);
    }
})
.controller("ControllerB", function(customService)
{
    customService.onIdChange(function(id)
    {
        // Do whatever you need to do with id
    });
});
```